Dataclass inheriting using kw_only for all variables
I am practicing on using the super function and dataclass inheritance in general. I have enabled the kw_only attribute for cases when the parent class has default values. I completely understand that super doesn't need to be used in a dataclass if you're just passing variables and I can avoid using super here. My goal is to understand the super feature better through this example. I can't understand the error message I'm getting though.
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class ZooAnimals():

    food_daily_kg: int
    price_food: float 
    area_required: float
    name: str 
   
    
c = ZooAnimals(food_daily_kg=565, price_food=40, area_required=10, name='Monkey'
              )

print(c)


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    meowing: str
    def __init__(self, food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, meowing, name):
        self.meowing = meowing
        super().__init__(food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, name)
        
            
z = Cats(food_daily_kg=465, price_food=30, area_required=10, meowing='Little Bit', 
         name='Leopard'
        )
print(z)

Output:
ZooAnimals(food_daily_kg=565, price_food=40, area_required=10, name='Monkey')

TypeError: ZooAnimals.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given


so, do you understand what passing kw_only=True does? It makes it so the generated __init__ only accepts keyword arguments. But then, you call that __init__ using only positional arguments here: super().__init__(food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, name)

@juanpa.arrivillaga totally understand what kw_only does, can you demonstrate how to pass keyword-only arguments to super()__init?

The syntax is similar, but you are confusing "default values" (a value defined when you define the function) with "keyword arguments" (a value provided using an explicit parameter name, instead of passing the argument positional).

@user4718221 I'm not sure you do understand, because then you would understand how to use keyword arguments. I'm not just trying to hassle you here, but I want you to really understand this. Here is an example of a function call using only positional arguments foo(1, "abc"), here is an example of a function call using keyword arguments, foo(some_param=1, another_param="abc") Here is a helpful entry in the official python glossary

You shouldn't define an __init__ method in a data class if you don't have any custom initialization logics. And if you do have custom initialization logics, you should define them in a __post_init__ method instead.
Your code produces the error because the __init__ method of the subclass calls the __init__ method of the base class with positional arguments when the method is configured to accept keyword arguments only with your kw_only=True option.
You can fix it by passing keyword arguments instead, or by simply removing the __init__ method from the subclass entirely since one would be generated for the data class with inheritance in mind already.
For example, this subclass definition would work just fine:
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    meowing: str

Demo here
Or if you would still like to define a custom __init__ method for some reason:
@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    meowing: str
    def __init__(self, food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, meowing, name):
        self.meowing = meowing
        super().__init__(
            food_daily_kg=food_daily_kg,
            price_food=price_food,
            area_required=area_required,
            name=name)

Demo here

Thank you for your answer. Could you demonstrate how do I pass keyword arguments into the subclass? As I mentioned in the post, I realize I don't need to bother with initialization and super in the dataclass when its only inheriting variables and doesn't change initialization. I am using this simple case to learn how super and kw_only work

You're welcome. I've updated the answer with an additional example then.
